# πίστις & ἐλπίζω related linguistically?

Tags: etymology, sound-change, compounds

This is stemming from a [question on BH-SE](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13935/what-is-the-difference-in-hope-and-faith).
Are faith (πίστις) and hope (ἐλπίς) related linguistically?
Is it at all possible that ἐλπίς is actually el/eli + πίστις or something + faith?
If not, is there any insight from linguistics into the differentiation between these two words?

Comment: Probly not. According to the AHD of PIE roots, πίστις comes from the PIE root [*bheidh](http://web.archive.org/web/20080629190710/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE49.html), while ἐλπίζω comes from PIE [*wel](http://web.archive.org/web/20080727015113/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE564.html).

Comment: Is their any possible insight on the meaning from the root and prefix/suffix of ἐλπίζω

Comment: Not unless you put it there. They're just morphemes, after all.

Comment: Can I ask that the words from that exotic language be rendered in IPA, as well as in their own obscure orthography?

Comment: Is Greek exotic?

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut Seriously? The Greek alphabet is still in use today, it's taught in high school in dozens of countries, it's used in math and is a parent of both the Latin and Cyrillic alphabets. "Obscure" might be a bit much. This is a site for linguistics after all!

Comment: Not much point in putting Classic Greek in IPA. **Nobody** would understand it then, since the language has no native speakers and no speech community, and any  pronunciations would be reconstructions.

Comment: Ok, sardonicism off: I would like to be able to read examples, even if the pronunciation is a very rough phonemic guess. I have no Greek (and usually work on languages that some others may consider exotic, but which seem entirely normal to me; it's a matter of perspective). Do we not then have limits on orthographic obscurity? Could I post a question or answer which uses examples rendered only in Cherokee, or perhaps Inuit orthography?

Comment: ἐλπίζω would be /˨ɛl˦pi˨zdɔ:/.  Or should I put the tone signs after their syllables?

Comment: @fdb Thanks! I'm quite happy for it to be in the original orthography, but having it in IPA *as well* allows those of us who have no Greek to read it and thereby to follow the discussion.

Answer (score 9):

These words are not considered to be related.

πίστις ‘faith, trust’ and the verb πείθομαι ‘to trust, obey, be persuaded’ come from Indo-European *bhidh-, related to Latin fides, with *bh- > *ph- > p according to Grassmann’s law.

ἐλπίς ‘hope’, ἐλπίζω, ἔλπομαι ‘to hope’, is from Indo-European *uelp-, perhaps cognate with Latin voluptas. There is no prefix involved.

(Partial overlap with jlawler.)

Comment: "Grassmann's law, named after its discoverer Hermann Grassmann, is a dissimilatory phonological process in Ancient Greek and Sanskrit which states that if an aspirated consonant is followed by another aspirated consonant in the next syllable, the first one loses the aspiration" [--Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann%27s_law).

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would edit the question but it wouldn't make much sense after.

1. So, let me explain that faith is πίστις but hope is not ἐλπίζω but `ελπίς`. Ελπίζω is the verb not the noun.
2. The etymology of those two words is not related:
   ἐλπίς < ἔλπω (make someone have hope)
   πίστη < πείθω

as you can see.
As for the conjugation it self is also different:
ελπίς (nominative) -> ελπίδος (genitive)
πίστις (nominative) -> πίστεως (genitive)

Comment: I edited the question based on what you said.  Thank you for your help and answer.